# How to send email from local machine to gmail?

Tags: php, email

I am just learning php and it's my first question on this site. Hope, you will help me. I just want to send Email from my local machine to gmail. I have tried but didn't got any success. Please help How to do this.
my code is


form processing


 

    return mail(
      $message['to'],
      join("\n", $headers))
};
?>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I suspect I misread the question. Do you want to use Gmail as your mail server or you're only sending messages to a Gmail recepient?

Answer (score 2):

You will want the `mail()` function see: [php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
mail('kushagra@gmail.com', 'My First Email', 'The body of my email');
```

You will need a mail server running on your local machine such as [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) for *nix or [Pegasus](http://www.pmail.com/) for Windows.

If you do not have the ability run a mail server on your machine then you might need to use a PHP class that allows you to connect to an SMTP server such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/).

Be aware though that a lot of ISPs will block connections on port 25 (SMTP) to protect against spamming (see my encounter of this with Optus a few years ago http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/374223466/optus-cable-port-25-smtp). If they are blocking it then you will need to use their SMTP server.

There is a tool linked in my blog post above which will allow you to determine if it is blocked or not see: http://www.zoneedit.com/smtp.html

Comment: I'm using WordPress, in my local machine, but my mails doesn't seem to  delivery.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales use the tips in the answer to get it working then!

Answer (score 1):

The standard builtin function to send mail in PHP is mail():

http://php.net/mail

Unfortunately, you cannot use it with Gmail since Gmail requires two security measures that are not supported by good old mail():

- Authentication
- Encryption

You need to find and download a third-party library. Popular choices include [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: I've had problems in the past with GMail rejecting email I tried to send, because I wasn't doing these things.  If I remember right, you'll get a generic, "we've detected excessive amounts of unsolicited mail from this IP" error message, which is just a little bit misleading.

Comment: I use the mail() function all the time in my web application and it rarely hits Gmail's spam folder. I must say I don't know exactly why, but maybe if you set the proper headers (like content-type), Gmail will leave it alone?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this [PHPMailer example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail) you could use Gmail as an SMTP server to send mail to your own account - guaranteed delivery!