# Can I send email to friends (say to gmail) from my local computer (IIS or Apache), if yes how?

Tags: email, iis, localhost, mail-server

I am planning to send email to my friends (they are in gmail and hotmail) from my local PC which I use at my home (in dynamic IP). Is it ever possible to configure IIS or Apache in my local PC and connect to home broadband and can send email?

I do not want to take any help from any other hosting company (as generally we do by using .Net or Php by taking SMTP address) so if need I can try to configure some website name to my PC (if possible).

I do not need to get any reply from them they will send again to my gmail address.

Is it ever possible as my plan?

Comment: You can install and set up a mail server such as Postfix on your home system but it's ridiculously complicated compared with just using a gmail account. Why the aversion to doing so, given you already have one?

Answer (score 0):

This question may be of some help to you: [How to send email from local machine to gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194040/how-to-send-email-from-local-machine-to-gmail?rq=1)

You should be able to run a .NET, PHP or other local web service on your home machine and use one of the libraries included in the link above to send e-mails without requiring a 3rd party web host. Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish exactly? There may be a simpler solution within gmail's API.

Comment: I do not want to use any API, I want to create own, like mymail@abcd.com or mymail@localhost.com. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can run a similar PHP/other mailing host as a hosting company might, but on your local machine, and send e-mails from there. Though as cms_mgr's comment notes, it can be a rather complex endeavor. Look into implementing http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ or a different library on your local machine as a service.

Comment: There has some misunderstanding from one side, I checked it. Here they are using

$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server

example.com want to be my local host. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have SMTP installed as a local web service on your localhost through IIS, then point $mail->Host = myLocalSmtpService.localhost/ or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to build a SMTP Server!

Things you will need

- STATIC IP.
- Reverse DNS from your ip to you hostname (type nslookup yourip on cmd.exe the result must be your hostname)
- DNS MX entry on your DNS ZONE like 0 your.host.name.com

A program/code that will implement the RFC2821 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

I have build a SMTP server that ONLY receive emails... maybe you can start from there....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834765/how-receive-emails-in-net-listening-connection-from-gmail-yahooo-not-a-pop